# SQL Query - Query on Current Date but condition from the past

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for help with the following scenario:

I have an SQL Server DB, with a table that stores historical data. For example lets use the following as a sample set.

```
CAR, SERVICE DATE, FINDINGS
1234, 21/01/2001, Fuel Filter
1234, 23/09/2009, Oil Change
1234, 30/09/2015, Tyres
3456, 30/09/2015, Clutch
```

I would like from the following sample to bring back the result that shows the service of any car that was brought in on a give date, e.g. 30/09/2015 but only if it had an oil change in the past.

The query would only bring back:

```
1234, 30/09/2015, Tyres
```

since it is the only car on that date to be services that previously had an oil change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer posted by Edwin failed for one use case..

Comment: You should carefully check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5931b/2) because solution provided by Edwin failed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT cur.car,
    cur.[service date],
    cur.findings
FROM tablename cur
WHERE cur.[service date] = @mydate
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tablename past
        WHERE past.car = cur.car
           AND past.[service date] < cur.[service date]
           AND past.findings = 'oil change'
    )
```

Comment: this is a perfect solution, but if you dont want to do a subquery and you prefer to do a join, you can inner join by "car" with the same table and filter both tables also :)

Comment: @IsmaelFuentes I would rather use `EXISTS` in this situation, because a `INNER JOIN` would require the use of `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @EdwinStoteler this is a wrong answer.. this fails for one use case when last to last service was OIL CHANGE..

Comment: @EdwinStoteler here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5931b/2) showing your query failed..

Comment: It certainly looks to me like it would work for every case.

Comment: @AmneshGoel I saw in a comment on a different answer, that if the last service was oil change it should not be included, unless it has had oil change before.

Comment: @EdwinStoteler Did you see the sqlfiddle..and still you feel that 1237 should be included in your answer?

Comment: 1237 had a prior oil change? maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t1.car
FROM table as t1
INNER JOIN table as t2 ON t1.car = t2.car AND t2.FINDINGS = 'Oil change' AND t2.[service date] < t1.[service date] is the other posibility i was talking about. And your answer seems good to me, i just wanted to help more, sorry for that...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid 1237 had a OIL CHANGE but not immediate prior to 30/9 service.. that is a tricky use case..

Comment: @AmneshGoel does not matter, as long as it had a oil change in the past. The requirements didn't say it needed to be the last service before the current date. So yes 1237 should be included.

Comment: @EdwinStoteler let it be.. I read question as last service should be oil change..`since it is the only car on that date to be services that previously had an oil change`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as a cte.

Find the list of cars that have had oil changed, then join back onto the original table to find the intersection.

```
DECLARE @date datetime;

SET @date = '20150930'

with oil_Cte as (
    select distinct car from
    tableName
    where findings = 'oil change'
    and date < @date
)

select *
from tableName
inner join oil_cte on tableName.car = oil_cte.car
where date = @date
```

Comment: This will not work, as this won't be able to differentiate the oil change with immediate previous oil change.. Wrong answer

Comment: How does that handle previous request?

Comment: @Neil P this will return multiple results if the car had it's oil changed more then once.

Comment: The select distinct should handle that :)

Comment: @NeilP Ok true, didn't see it. Not a big fan of distinct since it can hide bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This question had many conditions like

> - One of the service should happen on specified date.
> - Previous service to that date shoule only be 'Oil Change'. If previous service is not 'Oil Change' then don't include it in result,
>     even if it meets condition 1. Along with this, if car has record of
>     OIL Chagne in past then it doesn't matter.
> - If car had OIL CHANGE record but don't have service on that date then it should not consider.

You can try this solution.. and here is the working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5931b/1) for you

```
select * from #t where car in (
select car from (
select car, [service date], findings, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by car order by [Service Date] desc) as [row]
from (select * from #t where car in (select car from #t where [service date] = '2015-09-30')) A) T
where T.row =2 and Findings = 'Oil Change'
) and [service date] = '2015-09-30'
```